# Call a versioned webapi controller path ending with a number

Tags: c#, webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, api-versioning

Why does adding versioning to a webApi project removes number from the controller path name?

Replication steps :

1. Create a fresh .net6 project. And rename WeatherForecastController to WeatherForecast**2**Controller.
2. Run app and call https://localhost:**x**/WeatherForecast2 (where x is your port)
3. Observe valid/expected results
4. Add the below code in program.cs/startup

```c#
services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
{
    config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    config.ReportApiVersions = true;
    config.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(
        new QueryStringApiVersionReader("version"),
        new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-version"));
    config.UseApiBehavior = false;
});
```

5. Run app and call https://localhost:**x**/WeatherForecast2 (where x is your port).

Step 5 will return a 404 not found error.
However if you call https://localhost:**x**/WeatherForecast. It will work.

So why does adding versioning, change the url path?

Comment: I can see the benefit in having controller1,controller2,controllerN. all mapping to the same path with [controller], but this "hidden feature" caught me of guard since i had a descriptive name in my controller that ended up with a number

Comment: You set `QueryStringApiVersionReader`, so you should call `...WeatherForecast?version=1`.

Comment: No need, it should use default as i specified
AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified

Comment: The issue really happened in my side, I'm afraid it related with `ApiVersionReader`, but I didn't find how  `ApiVersionReader` manage the controller name. So my idea here is that you may try to avoid using number as the end of the controller name. Or you may try to avoid using `[controller]` to be the route.

Comment: Yep, I fixed it by being explicit with the route name instead of `[controller]`. Couldn't find any documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear if you are using <= `5.0` or `6.0`+.

#### History

The reason this behavior happens is because the only logical way to group controllers together is by their names. A controller name, therefore, becomes very important. This is problematic in code because two or more controllers in the same namespace cannot have the same type name. The assumption and long-defined convention has been to allow ASP.NET to remove the `Controller` suffix and then remove any remaining numbers. This allows `ValuesController`, `Values2Controller` and `Values3Controller` to all map to the logical controller name `Values` by default. In most cases, that's probably want someone wants. If API Versioning doesn't do this, then there is no way to collate all API versions together for an API.

Contrary to popular belief, route templates are **not** considered for grouping  controllers (e.g. APIs). There is too much ambiguity as to how a template can map to code. Take the simplest example of two different versions of the same API with different route templates: V1 = `values/{id}`, V2 = `values/{id:int}`. These are semantically equivalent, but not the same. API Versioning does not try to understand what the route template means nor compare their equivalence. It can easily get a lot more complicated; especially, for overlapping route templates. For example, should `order/{oid}/customer/{cid}` be part of the *Orders* API or the *Customer* API? Only the service author knows for sure.

#### Regression

In the `5.0` release, a regression was accidentally introduced due to an over-optimization. The controller name is used in two places: the actual name of the  controller and the name used to group controllers. It seems reasonable they'd be the same and why normalize (e.g. trim suffixes) more than necessary? It seemed like a good idea, but it caused unexpected behavior - such as this one. There are also legitimate reasons to have a number in the name of a controller; for example, `S3Controller`.

#### Fix

In library versions <= `5.0`, developers had no control over the behavior of how names were normalized. In `5.1` and `6.0`+, this is now exposed via the `IControllerNameConvention` service, which has two methods: one for normalizing the controller name and one for normalizing the group name. The following implementations are provided out of the box as properties on `ControllerNameConvention`:

- `Default`: The default, out-of-the-box conventions
- `Original`: The original names without any normalization (could result in the wrong behavior)
- `Grouped`: The group name is normalized, but the controller name is unmodified

If none of those work for you, then you can create your own custom convention. In `5.1` this is wired up via `ApiVersioningOptions.ControllerNameConvention`, while in `6.0`+ `IControllerNameConvention` is a transient service in the DI container.

#### Workaround

There are two ways you can workaround the problem using the current version you are leveraging:

##### Explicit Route Template

If you omit using the `[controller]` token, the routing problem will be resolved; for example, `api/weatherforecast`. You appear to have already discovered this.

##### Explicit Controller Name

The controller name is derived from a convention, even without API Versioning. It was understood this behavior *could* be a problem so API Versioning provides a way to explicit set it with the **ControllerNameAttribute**.

```cs
[ControllerName("WeatherForecast")]
[Route("api/[controller]")] // ← expands to 'api/WeatherForecast'
public class WeatherForecast2Controller : ControllerBase { }
```

##### Edge Case

This will solve the routing issues, but it will **not** fix the controller name issue. That should only matter if you are planning on documenting your API with OpenAPI (formerly Swagger). For example, `S3Controller` will simply show up as `S`, even though the route might be `api/s3`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your controller may have issues, as I used your `AddApiVersioning` code and it works for me. To avoid the conflicting action names, you can two different controllers.

ApiController

```
namespace WebApiVersioningApp.Controllers;

[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/Version2")]
public class Version2Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecastV1")]
    public string GetV1()
    {
        return "Version 1";
    }
    
    [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecastV2")]
    public string GetV2()
    {
        return "Version 2";
    }
}
```

Program:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First())
);

// Versioning setup
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
{
    o.ReportApiVersions = true;
    o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    o.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(
        new QueryStringApiVersionReader("version"),
        new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-version"));
    o.UseApiBehavior = false;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Your `public class VersionController` does not have a number in the name.

Comment: Renamed it with a number. I can still get a response when I call ```https://localhost:7297/api/Version2``` with query string and header.